# Are sub-interfaces the solution to default-method conflicts?

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8, default-method

Consider the following code, which is an extraction of a real use case where `LinkedList<E>` implements both `List<E>` and `Deque<E>`.

One can observe that both interfaces have a `size()` and an `isEmpty()` method, where the `isEmpty()` method could be made default in terms of `size()`.

So, let's do that (with dummy interfaces), since Java 8 does not do it yet:

```
interface List<E> {
    public int size();

    default public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size() == 0);
    }

    //more list operations
}

interface Deque<E> {
    public int size();

    default public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size() == 0);
    }

    //more deque operations
}

class LinkedList<E> implements List<E>, Deque<E> {
    private int size;

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Oops! We get a compile-time error on `LinkedList`, as it does not know which `isEmpty()` implementation to use, so we add this:

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return List.super.isEmpty();
}
```

Now we have lost practically all benefits of default methods for this use case, as it still takes us as much code to write the `isEmpty()` method as it did before.

**But can it be solved? Yes!**

Consider the following implementation:

```
interface Sizable {
    public int size();

    default public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size() == 0);
    }
}

interface List<E> extends Sizable {
    //list operations
}

interface Deque<E> extends Sizable {
    //deque operations
}

class LinkedList<E> implements List<E>, Deque<E> {
    private int size;

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

So the **question**:

- Is this how we, and also the JDK, are supposed to handle it in future implementations?

Comment: Just to let you know, in your example, `Collection` interface has `size` and `isEmpty` methods, and both `List` and `Deque` extend from `Collection`... But yes, looks like that's they way it has to be now.

Comment: The point of default methods is not to let you write fewer methods, with fewer lines of code (although 1 line of code doesn't look bad to me). The point of default methods is to be able to introduce new methods in interfaces without breaking existing implementations.

Comment: @JBNizet Should default methods, as secondary goal, not be used to ensure that implementors of an interface have less work to do?

Comment: When creating a new interface with a default method _foobar_, is there any way to know in advance, that somebody will later inherit from your interface and also from some other interface of a completely unrelated library, that accidentally contains a default method with the same name and signature?

Comment: @nosid In this case both interfaces are 'yours' though... If there's really two totally unrelated things, then you're correct that it's not possible.

Comment: @skiwi: they can be used with this goal, obviously. But if the implementor chooses to override two different interfaces having a common default method, then the implementor will have to override the method and choose the version he wants (or reimplement it). That's just one line of code needed. I wouldn't call that a problem.

Comment: +1. I tend to see this as a solution in search of a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly discourage from adding super-interfaces for unrelated interfaces just for defining `default` methods. Normally, you don’t have that problem as either, the interfaces *are* related like in your example so that a natural super-interface like `Collection` exists or could be defined for more than just providing `default` methods. Or they are really unrelated and a `class` implementing both is either unlikely or will have to define which semantics to inherit, anyway.

In case of the `Collection` API having no `default` method for `isEmpty` is intentional as `size` can be an expensive operation for some `Collection`s. If your `Collection` shares behavior with typical `Collection`s you may inherit from `AbstractCollection`.

Comment: Is that no the point of the ability to override default methods? If the `isEmpty` *can* be calculated easier, then you should provide such implementation in your concrete class. I believe we have the same issue with for example a custom implementaiton of a `LinkedList`, where even though we have default functionality for some methods, we wish to override it for better behaviour. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You explicitly choose to inherit a particular implementation when subclassing, e.g. `AbstractList` or `AbstractSequentialList`. An `interface` should not foist an implementation to its implementors. Of course, a certain implementation might be so common that a decision to add a `default` seems naturally, like with `Iterator.remove`. But unlike `Collection`s, `Iterator`s are usually implemented without the aid of an `abstract` base class. There are a lot of `Collection` methods for which a default can be provided, but `AbstractCollection` does that already.